# /index/ doesn't pull 404 looks similar to index.php but doesn't show css

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I do not have a /index/ folder yet if I visit myname.com/index/ it pulls up the data on index.php but doesn't display the css because /index/style.css doesn't exist. I have tested this with many directory urls that do not exist, it's all the same thing.

/about/ pulls up the about.php page
/contact/ pulls up the contact.php page

only will a 404 occur when I try to load a url where a matching .php page doesn't exist.

Example: /blablabla/ returns a 404 because blablabla.php doesn't exist.

How do I make it so that /about/ /contact/ /index/ and other directories that have a matching .php file return a 404?

Here is a copy of my config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@yourname.com
        ServerName yourname.com
        ServerAlias www.yourname.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yourname.com/public_html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/yourname.com/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/yourname.com/public_html/cgi-bin/

        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        LogLevel warn


     ErrorLog /var/www/yourname.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/yourname.com/logs/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

  <IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive on 
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/js "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 day"
   ExpiresDefault "access 7 days" 
  </IfModule>

# Turn on Expires and set default to 0
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

# Set up caching on media files for 1 year (forever?)
<filesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A29030400
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files for 1 week
<filesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>

# Set up 2 Hour caching on commonly updated files
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A7200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<filesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</filesMatch>


# 480 weeks
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</filesMatch>

# 2 DAYS
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

# 2 HOURS
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is a copy of the .htaccess file in /var/www/yourname.com/public_html

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/www/yourname.com/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files admin.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
<Files systeminfo.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

There's really nothing in my .htaccess that I think would be causing this problem. Basically I am just password protecting two files located on the parent directory.

Comment: That's certainly not standard behavior, so pasting in the relevant sections of your httpd config of htaccess file is crucial to figuring out why.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just edited the post to include the .htaccess and virtual host file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing that because you've turned [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) on.

> A MultiViews search is enabled by the MultiViews Options. If the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document.

Try changing the line:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

to:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Or just remove the `MultiViews` option altogether. Unless there's some reason you have it turned on?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. I do not see why I would need that. I think that was part of the original default that eventually morphed into what you see above. I went ahead and added -MultiViews as opposed to removing it. Just curious, what is the difference between removing it and adding the (-) minus in front of it?